# MVC 3 - SignalR moveshape sample

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I trying to adopt the demo in this article http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-high-frequency-realtime-with-signalr which is developed with vS2012, however I am using vs2010.
I made the model:

```
  [HubName("moveShapeHub")]
    public class MoveShapeHub : Hub
    {
        public void UpdateModel(ShapeModel clientModel)
        {
            clientModel.LastUpdatedBy = Context.ConnectionId;
            Clients.AllExcept(clientModel.LastUpdatedBy).updateShape(clientModel);
        }
    }
```

Modified Global.cs:

```
  protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
        }
```

In the view:

```
 var moveShapeHub = $.connection.moveShapeHub,
        $shape = $("#shape"),

            shapeModel = {
                left: 0,
                top: 0
            };

        moveShapeHub.client.updateShape = function (model) {
            shapeModel = model;
            $shape.css({ left: model.left, top: model.top });
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $shape.draggable({
                drag: function () {
                    shapeModel = $shape.offset();
                    moveShapeHub.server.updateModel(shapeModel);
                }
            });
```

I get the following error:
Unable to get property 'client' of undefined or null reference.

Any idea what I am doing wrong; would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not including the following code in your HTML:

```
<script src='/signalr/hubs'></script>
```

Make sure that that code snippet is included AFTER your inclusion of the signalr js library.

If you're still adding the script tag correctly then you're having a path misunderstanding issue where your server is being hosted on a different port.

Lets say your sample is running on `http://localhost:1337`, you can view your signalr/hubs file by going to `http://localhost:1337/signalr/hubs` in your browser and you should get generated JavaScript.

A common issue that people run into is they include the /signalr/hubs file but they host their site on `http://localhost:1337/bar/`.  Therefore SignalR tries to load the hubs file from `http://localhost:1337/signalr/hubs` when really it's located at `http://localhost:1337/bar/signalr/hubs`.

Verify that your inclusion of /signalr/hubs is  pointing to the correct location. I usually do:

```
<script src="<%: ResolveUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>"></script>
```

To always resolve the App-relative URL.

Also be sure to call `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();` BEFORE you map any other routes.

Comment: Thank you, I made the change and even moved all js to the master view still get the same error.  I wish there is a simple VS2010 MVC3 sample, most of the examples I found are built in VS2012.

Comment: If you manually go to your version of http://localhost:1337/signalr/hubs in a web browser do you see the generated javascript page?

Comment: I get HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.

Comment: Ahh missed this the first time around, you need to do RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs() BEFORE you map any other routes.  So move that line to the top of your application start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that connection is being established with the server, if not add a `.fail(function(){
alert("failed to connect")});` to the end of your connection.hub.start method, to see if it is connecting ok, afterwards try this method:

```
moveShapeHub.on('updateShape', function(model) {
        shapeModel = model;
        $shape.css({ left: model.left, top: model.top });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I got this error:
SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/hubs'></script>

Comment: Add reference to scripts in the following order: jquery, signalr, signalr/hubs before the executing JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly the order I have; I must be doing something else wrong!